# running automation tests with appium-flutter-driver not working

Tags: flutter, dart, automation, appium

I am trying to detect element like `Text` and `MaterialButton` (Flutter Widgets) on appium inspector.

i have tried `Semantics`, but of course, we are not going to wrap all elements in `Semantics`, and also even when using that, QA team could not retrieve the data from the Widget like string from a `Text` widget.

So, i have used **appium-flutter-driver** and sets a my custom `Key` to some widget.
when using `appium:automationName` as `"Flutter"` ,  to start the driver, appium inspector hangs.

Also, i have used `semanticLabel` on a Text Widget without **appium-flutter-driver** and using. but, its only for `Text` Widgets and still QA team could not retrieve data.

this is my ispector Json:

```
{
  "appium:deviceName": "iPhone 14 Pro",
  "appium:automationName": "Flutter",
  "appium:platformVersion": "16.2",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "appium:app": "../Desktop/Runner.zip",
  "appium:wdaLocalPort": "8100"
}
```

I am expecting to detect Flutter Widgets with appium inspector with the best practice system.